# Calling a function to a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with some syntax regarding a function I made and running it a few times in a loop.
Here is the function I put in the scrip tag:

```
function getAmountSpent(){
   // your code goes here
   var amountSpent = (Math.random() * 500) + 1));
   return amountSpent.toFixed(2)
}
```

The function is supposed to generate a random number from 1-500, rounded to two decimal places.

This function is supposed to be called by a loop array. It is supposed to loop 5 times. This is what I have currently

```
var spent =
```

as you could tell I didn't really get very far. I understand that I need to use a "for" loop, which I think should go like this.

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
```

The array "spent" is called later in the html by a button

```
<th><button id = "amount" onclick ='
    //these values should be numbers between 0 and 500
    amount0.value = "$" + spent[0];
    amount1.value = "$" + spent[1];
    amount2.value = "$" + spent[2];
    amount3.value = "$" + spent[3];
    amount4.value = "$" + spent[4];
    ' >Amount Spent</button></th>
```

this button declares the values for amount0,amount1,etc...

which is displayed in text boxes at the end of the html document.

If you guys could help me help call the function getAmountSpent to work within the spent array, that would be of great help to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push the result onto the `spent` array in the loop.

```js
function getAmountSpent() {
  var amountSpent = Math.random() * 500 + 1;
  return amountSpent.toFixed(2)
}

let spent = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  spent.push(getAmountSpent());
}
```

```html
<input id="amount0">
<input id="amount1">
<input id="amount2">
<input id="amount3">
<input id="amount4">

<button id = "amount" onclick ='
    //these values should be numbers between 0 and 500
    amount0.value = "$" + spent[0];
    amount1.value = "$" + spent[1];
    amount2.value = "$" + spent[2];
    amount3.value = "$" + spent[3];
    amount4.value = "$" + spent[4];
    ' >Amount Spent</button>
```

Comment: `function getAmountSpent(){
   
  var amountSpent = (Math.random() * 500) + 1));
  return amountSpent.toFixed(2)
 }
 
 var names = ["Jeremy","Arun","Alisa","Rohan","Dana"];
 
 var spent = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    spent.push(getAmountSpent());
 } `

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced in `getAmountSpent()`

Comment: was able to get it to work, much appreciated Barmar